# Where to find the low latency stylus API used by Squid?

Tags: android, stylus-pen

Where can I find the ***low latency stylus API*** used by [Squid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadfastinnovation.android.projectpapyrus) application?
This is an excerpt from Android website mentioning it.
[Page](https://developer.android.com/stories/apps/squid#what_they_did)

> The biggest and most beneficial effort was adding support for the low
>   latency stylus API, which drastically improved the core experience of
>   Squid. Since Squid is a handwritten note-taking app, stylus
>   integration is extremely important because an active pen provides a
>   much more natural writing experience. Squid users are astonished at
>   how fluid and lag-free writing is now. With low-latency support, the
>   ink finally feels like it's coming out of the pen.